# Qpid Proton CPP issue with exchanges

Tags: c++, qpid

I am having an issue with the most trivial step in Qpid Proton. Here's my setup

```
 qpid-config -a localhost:5672 add exchange test.announce
 qpid-config -a localhost:5672 add queue test.announce.q
 qpid-config -a localhost:5672 bind test.announce test.announce.q
```

(no routing key specified intentionally)
When I run the proton cpp server and client with the following

```
 ./server -a amqp://127.0.0.1:5672/test.announce
 ./client -a amqp://127.0.0.1:5672/test.announce.q
```

the client fails to communicate with the server. But using the standalone qpid tools

```
qpid-receive -a test.announce.q -b 127.0.0.1:5672  -t -f
echo "hello world!!!"|qpid-send -b 127.0.0.1:5672 -a test.announce -m 1 --content-stdin
```

this works as expected.
Running qpid-send against the Proton server also seems to work fine. I do not see anything in the Proton message API that I can update and not sure what I'm missing here. The server and client code are pretty much identical to what's in 0.12 snapshot. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

I realized my mistake. The concept of server and client in AMQP seem somewhat reversed. I changed the apps so that client "sent" on exchange while server listened on queue and everything worked.

```
 ./server -a amqp://127.0.0.1:5672/test.announce.q
 ./client -a amqp://127.0.0.1:5672/test.announce
```